# Finding a specific file in a directory

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy text file in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512271/how-to-copy-text-file-in-c-or-c)

I need a code which specifically look up a directory and find a pre-specified file name then copy it to another folder. It sounds easy but couldnt do it. Can anbody help me?
thanks

Comment: Dont know how to start. I am using windows platform and visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Some functions you may find useful from WINAPI:

- [FindFirstFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CopyFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

boost has a [filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html) which has a [copy_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file) function.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, C++ doesn't offer a file copy function. You need to open the file, read in its data into a local buffer, then make a new file, and write the contents of the local buffer into the new file.

[File IO Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)