# moving a file across volumes with C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, move

I'm trying to write something that moves files across volumes on all platforms. Currently, I use the rename(...) function to move the files, and this works, even across volumes/drives on Windows. However, on Linux, I get an EXDEV error (via strace), killing my app :(

It appears that I may need to call 'mv' via system(...) but this seems very hacky. That, or integrate boost into my app, which is not a trivial operation.

Are there any other options available to me?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512271/how-to-copy-text-file-in-c-or-c

Comment: @KerrekSB - "on **all** platforms"...

Comment: If you want to do exactly the same thing as POSIX mv, you can look at the source for the BSD implementation. IIRC, it tries rename, then on EXDEV it uses code shared with the cp command (which is hundreds of lines of code to get right things like transfering file metadata appropriately, etc.), then calls unlink if it succeeds. If you want to get all of that exactly right, you may be better off just using the BSD code instead of writing it yourself. If you don't care, hmjd's link gives you a much simpler answer (actually, a few of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write something that is required to be cross-platform and not rely on system-specific implementations - you must stick to the standard. While newer the C++11 standard may allow additional features to help you with that, a trivial solution would be to just implement a plain copy from one `fstream` to another.