# C++ copying text files with iterators

Tags: c++, file, text, iterator, copy

I just found a way to copy a file with iterators to another file:

```
ifstream ifile("file1.txt");
ofstream ofile("file2.txt");
copy(istream_iterator<string>(ifile),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     ostream_iterator<string>(ofile, " "));
```

It works, but unfortunately all text from "file1.txt" is in only one line at "file2.txt", but oryginally at "file1.txt" are many lines.

I tried to change string between iterator's loop:

```
copy(istream_iterator<string>(ifile),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     ostream_iterator<string>(ofile, "\n"));
```

but result at "file2.txt" is worse - every word is in different line.

My question: 
is any way to copy file with iterators but without loosing any informations, or should I do it with `getline()`?

Comment: Maybe try it with `<char>`. I can't say for sure if it will work, but it's an idea.

Comment: Use [istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator).

Comment: string will stop when it encounters first newline...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512271/how-to-copy-text-file-in-c-or-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`istream_iterator<T> iter(stream)` will use formatted input functions, so that `++iter` is somewhat equivalent to:

```
T t;
stream >> t;
```

For `string` objects this means discarding any leading whitespace and reading only until the next whitespace character.

If you want unformatted operations instead, use `istreambuf_iterator<char>` (as was noted in the comments).

Comment: the option below works thanks to you:
        ifstream ifile("main.cc");
        ofstream ofile("main_copy.cc");
        copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifile),
        istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ofile));

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using iterators and `std::getline()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

// Define a struct and operator>> for reading lines.
//
struct line
{
    std::string buf;
    operator std::string() const { return buf; }
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& a_in, line& a_line)
{
    return std::getline(a_in, a_line.buf);
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("main.cpp");
    std::ofstream out("copy.cpp");

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<line>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<line>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unset the skip whitespace flag on the ifstream.

```
ifile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/unsetf.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  The answer should be correct.  The skip whitespace flag is usually on by default, because usually people are expected to use input streams to grab whitespace delimited values. Unsetting the skipws flag solves his problem.

Comment: I agree with you and I also don't understand why it was downvoted, thanks for You it works:
  ifstream ifile("main.cc");
  ofstream ofile("main_copy.cc");
  ifile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
  copy(istream_iterator<char>(ifile),
      istream_iterator<char>(),
      ostream_iterator<char>(ofile, ""));